# VisualCode IntelliSense Jasmine Typings seem not to work

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript-typings

I have installed typings of jasmine in my project. These are now located in my "index.d.ts" file. However when writing tests, `expect('').toBeNaN`, I only get shown "toBe", nothing more.

These are my config files:

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
      },
      "filesGlob": [
        "**/*.ts",
        "!node_modules/**/*"
      ],
      "include": [
        "typings/index.d.ts"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
      ],
      "compileOnSave": false,
      "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
      }
    }
```

This is my **index.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="globals/jasmine-expect/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/karma-jasmine/index.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed the incorrect version. Try installing the following from typings.

```
typings install dt~jasmine --global --save-dev
```

As of this writing, this installs version 2.2.0.